# Installating Resurrection Remix on HTC One X

Tags: rom-flashing, clockworkmod-recovery

I have a HTC One X (International model) and have been trying to install Resurrection Remix as a way to get a more modern Android version. I've unlocked the bootloader and installed [ClockworkMod Recovery](https://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager) 6.0.4.8. I cannot get Resurrection Remix installed. I keep getting this error:

> Your recovery is using the new storage layout but the ROM you're trying to install is not.
>   Flash a compatible recovery and format /data and /sdcard or use a compatible ROM.

I've tried 6 different versions of Resurrection Remix, the latest one being [cm-12-20150228-UNOFFICIAL-endeavoru-big.zip](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=95916177934535306). It explicitly states it uses the new storage layout, though I still get that error. I followed the steps described in [this blog post](http://www.android.gs/upgrade-htc-one-x-to-android-5-1-1-lollipop-with-resurrection-remix-custom-rom/), and I've also been Googling the error. It seems other people have run into it, though I can't find any actual solution.

Should I be using another ROM? Should I use an older/different version of ClockworkMod? Is the error wrong and caused by some issue not related to the ROM layout?

Answer (score 0):

I've now managed to make a working installation. I followed [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77AtaASGljA) and the [blog post it links](http://onexroot.com/one-x-roms/how-to-install-cm12lollipop-rom-on-htc-one-x/). The main difference being the usage of a special version of TWRP rather than ClockworkMod Recovery. Note that the android version included there is 5.0.2, so you might want to use a more recent one instead.

Comment: Hi, whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Consider [edit]ing to summarize the content and/or expand the answer!